# json returns undefined when accessing in ajax

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a controller that return json object I checked the controller and it's working good.

Here is the Sample Result of my controller

```
{"CompliantCount":0,"NonCompliantCount":0,"StatusOfRiskItems":[{"Id":4,"Status":"Closed","Count":0},{"Id":1,"Status":"Open","Count":0},{"Id":2,"Status":"Mitigating Control Implemented","Count":0},{"Id":3,"Status":"Risk Accepted","Count":0}],"RiskLevelBreakdownOfOpenItems":[{"Id":0,"RiskLevel":"N/A","Count":0},{"Id":1,"RiskLevel":"Low","Count":0},{"Id":2,"RiskLevel":"Medium","Count":0},{"Id":3,"RiskLevel":"High","Count":0},{"Id":4,"RiskLevel":"Very High","Count":0}],"RiskLevelStatusPerDepartment":[],"CompliancePerDepartment":[],"CurrentRiskLevel":"N/A","ComplianceRating":NaN}
```

But when I consume the json in ajax it return null

```
function RiskRegisterReport(siteId, programId, departmentId, status, auditType, auditor, auditDate) {
  var _data;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    url: hostpath + "/RiskRegister/RiskRegisterReport/",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    data: {
        siteId: siteId,
        programId: programId,
        departmentId: departmentId,
        statusId: status,
        auditType: auditType,
        auditor: auditor,
        auditDate: auditDate
    },
    success: function (data) {
        /// after getting the data
        /// push  the data.Compliant and data.NonCompiant to the array
        _data = data;
    }
  });
  return _data;
}
```

Comment: How controller looks like ?

Comment: This will not work as the return will be called before ajax response receive you will have to put some wait condition or check that the _data variable is set or not before returning that value

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I think the problem is in the ajax because when the controller return  [] value it return undefine

Comment: Got It!.. The problem is that the json is not valid because it has a NAN value.."ComplianceRating":NaN .. Thanks guys.. @Arun P Johny the article is awesome.. thanks dude..